# Performing LEFT JOIN on an AGGREGATE SUM from a different table

Tags: mysql, left-join, aggregate

I have two tables (defects, sort_data) and I would like to perform a combination of an aggregate sum and a left join on them to show all defect names, ordered from the highest qty aggregate sum in sort_data and also including defects not present in the sort_data table.  See below.

```
defects
defect_name
-----------
Snapped     
Cracked     
Melted      
Warped      
Other       

sort_data
defect_name |qty
----------------
Snapped     |5
Cracked     |1
Snapped     |15
Snapped     |10
Melted      |2

Desired results: 
Snapped
Melted
Cracked
Other
Warped
```

I am able to create the part of the list from sort_data by using an aggregate sum:

```
SELECT sort_data.defect_name, sum(qty) 
FROM sort_data 
GROUP BY sort_data.defect_name 
ORDER BY sum(qty)
```

I believe that I also need a left join like:

```
SELECT * 
from defects 
LEFT OUTER JOIN sort_data on sort_data.defect_name = defects.defect_name
```

I'm not sure how to combine the two. Help would be appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use left join

```
SELECT defect.defect_name, sum(sort_data.qty) 
FROM defect 
LEFT JOIN sort_data on sort_data.defect_name = defects.defect_name
GROUP BY sort_data.defect_name 
ORDER BY sum(sort_data.qty);
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for.